# Android - Using If statement when button is clicked to call a function

Tags: android, function, if-statement

I have multiple onClickListeners that are called when I change the theme of my app. I am using images and colors to change the background of my app and the images and colors also change based on what theme you have chosen. There are two separate functions that are called in OnCreate  i.e., setLayoutBGColor() and setLayoutBGImage(), whenever I change my background image or color. The problem is that I need to use an if statement that checks whether the user has clicked on one of the colors or images and then call the function based on that.
I can't add the full onCreate function as it is exceeding the word limit

**CreateNote class OnCreate function:**

```
 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_create_note);
    
         
            coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.layoutBGcolor);
            layoutCopyNote = findViewById(R.id.copyNote);
            bgColorView = findViewById(R.id.bgColorImageView);
            theme = Utils.getTheme(this);
    
             
            if(theme == 1) {
                selectedNoteColor = "#333333";
            }
            else{
                selectedNoteColor = "#FFFFFF";
            }
            selectedColorIndex = 0;
            selectedImagePath = "";
            selectedNoteBgImage = "";
            selectedImageIndex = 0;
   
            initMisc();
    
            //add an if else statement
            setLayoutBGColor();
            setLayoutBGImage();
        }
```

**InitMisc Function where all the listeners are mentioned:**

```
private void initMisc() {
        layoutMisc = findViewById(R.id.layoutMisc);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(layoutMisc);
        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.textMisc).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                } else {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                }
            }
        });

        final ImageView noColor = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_color_note);
        final ImageView imageColor1 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.imageColor1);
        final ImageView imageColor2 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.imageColor2);
        final ImageView imageColor3 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.imageColor3);
        final ImageView imageColor4 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.imageColor4);
        final ImageView imageColor5 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.imageColor5);

        final ImageView noBgImage = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_bg_image);
        final  ImageView bgImage1 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgImage1);
        final ImageView bgImage2 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgImage2);
        final ImageView bgImage3 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgImage3);
        final ImageView bgImage4 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgImage4);
        final ImageView bgImage5 = layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgImage5);

        theme = Utils.getTheme(this);
        switch (theme) {
            case 2:
                        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_color).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            selectedNoteColor = "#FFFFFF";
                            selectedColorIndex = 0;
                            noColor.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg_done_remove_day);
                            noColor.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done);
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DefaultNoteColorDay));
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#FFFFFF";
                            selectedColorIndex = 0;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#CCF49E";
                            selectedColorIndex = 1;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#F8A39D";
                            selectedColorIndex = 2;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#93CCC6";
                            selectedColorIndex = 3;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#EFD074";
                            selectedColorIndex = 4;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    if (availableNote != null && availableNote.getColor() != null && !availableNote.getColor().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        switch (availableNote.getColor()) {
                            case "#FFFFFF":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color1).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#CCF49E":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color2).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#F8A39D":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color3).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#93CCC6":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color4).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#EFD074":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color5).performClick();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
   
                        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_background).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#FFFFFF";
                            selectedColorIndex = 0;
                            noBgImage.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg_done_remove_day);
                            noBgImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done);
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DefaultNoteColorDay));
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_1";
                            selectedImageIndex = 0;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_2";
                            selectedImageIndex = 1;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_3";
                            selectedImageIndex = 2;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_4";
                            selectedImageIndex = 3;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_5";
                            selectedImageIndex = 4;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });
                    if (availableNote != null && availableNote.getNote_background_image() != null && !availableNote.getNote_background_image().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        switch (availableNote.getNote_background_image()) {
                            case "background_image_1":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage1).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_2":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage2).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_3":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage3).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_4":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage4).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_5":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage5).performClick();
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                break;
            default:
                       layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_color).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#333333";
                            selectedColorIndex = 0;
                            noColor.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg_done_remove);
                            noColor.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done);
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DefaultNoteColor));
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#333333";
                            selectedColorIndex = 0;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#354A36";
                            selectedColorIndex = 1;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#3E2C47";
                            selectedColorIndex = 2;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#26534F";
                            selectedColorIndex = 3;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });
                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#000000";
                            selectedColorIndex = 4;
                            imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
                            imageColor5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            setLayoutBGColor();
                        }
                    });

                    if (availableNote != null && availableNote.getColor() != null && !availableNote.getColor().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        switch (availableNote.getColor()) {
                            case "#333333":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color1).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#354A36":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color2).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#3E2C47":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color3).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#26534F":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color4).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "#000000":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color5).performClick();
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_background).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteColor = "#333333";
                            selectedColorIndex = 0;
                            noBgImage.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.bg_done_remove);
                            noBgImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done);
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DefaultNoteColor));
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_1_night";
                            selectedImageIndex = 0;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_2_night";
                            selectedImageIndex = 1;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage3).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_3_night";
                            selectedImageIndex = 2;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_4_night";
                            selectedImageIndex = 3;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(0);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });

                    layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            selectedNoteBgImage = "background_image_5_night";
                            selectedImageIndex = 4;
                            bgImage1.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage2.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage3.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage4.setImageResource(0);
                            bgImage5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                            setLayoutBGImage();
                        }
                    });
                    if (availableNote != null && availableNote.getNote_background_image() != null && !availableNote.getNote_background_image().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        switch (availableNote.getNote_background_image()) {
                            case "background_image_1_night":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage1).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_2_night":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage2).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_3_night":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage3).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_4_night":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage4).performClick();
                                break;

                            case "background_image_5_night":
                                layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.bgColorImage5).performClick();
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                break;
        }
```

**the two Functions:**

```
private void setLayoutBGColor(){
        coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(getColorCodeFromColorIndex(selectedColorIndex))));
        bgColorView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getResources().getString(getColorCodeFromColorIndex(selectedColorIndex))));
    }

    private void setLayoutBGImage(){
        coordinatorLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(getImageCodeFromImageIndex(selectedImageIndex)));
    }
```

Comment: `as it is exceeding the word limit` - which word limit? . Also I see a lot a repetitive code in `initMisc()` which could be replaced by using a common method.

Comment: I am sorry, I am quite new in this field. I apologize if my coding style offended you in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code, using this pattern:

```java
private void setImageResources(int id) {
        imageColor1.setImageResource(0);
        imageColor2.setImageResource(0);
        imageColor3.setImageResource(0);
        imageColor4.setImageResource(0);
        imageColor5.setImageResource(0);

        theme = Utils.getTheme(this);
        switch (id) {
            default:
            case R.id.no_color:
                selectedNoteColor = theme==2? "#FFFFFF": "#333333";
                selectedColorIndex = 0;
                coordinatorLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.DefaultNoteColorDay));
                return;
            case R.id.color1:
                selectedNoteColor = theme==2? "#FFFFFF": "#333333";
                selectedColorIndex = 0;
                imageColor1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                break;
            case R.id.color2:
                selectedNoteColor = theme==2? "#CCF49E": "#354A36";
                selectedColorIndex = 1;
                imageColor2.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                break;
            case R.id.color3:
                selectedNoteColor = theme==2? "#F8A39D": "#3E2C47";
                selectedColorIndex = 2;
                imageColor3.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                break;
            case R.id.color4:
                selectedColorIndex = 3;
                selectedNoteColor = theme==2? "#93CCC6": "#26534F";
                imageColor4.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                break;
            case R.id.color5:
                selectedColorIndex = 4;
                selectedNoteColor = theme==2? "#EFD074": "#000000";
                imageColor5.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_create);
                break;
        }

        setLayoutBGColor();
    }
```

and set listeners in `initMisc`:

```java
        View.OnClickListener listener = v-> setImageResource(v.getId());

        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.no_color).setOnClickListener(listener);
        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color1).setOnClickListener(listener);
        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color2).setOnClickListener(listener);
        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color3).setOnClickListener(listener);
        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color4).setOnClickListener(listener);
        layoutMisc.findViewById(R.id.color5).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: Thank you for the sophisticated version of code. I am quite new to all this and didn't know it could have been written in such format.

Comment: It's okay, the most difficult part is to start ^_^

Comment: One question, can you kindly tell in which function all the listeners that you mentioned above should be written.

Comment: edited the answer, the listeners are set in `initMisc` instead of the `switch(theme)` block, if you want, I can edit in the entire `initMisc` function to the answer

Comment: No, thank you so much. You've already been very helpful